# creating a HMAC SHA256 key in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to properly create a new HMAC key to interact with an API. However I keep on hitting obstacle after obstacle. I've copied the code from the API documents to create the authentication message but it keeps throwing errors.

```
class CoinbaseExchangeAuth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key
        self.passphrase = passphrase

    def __call__(self, request):
        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or '')
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
        signature_b64 = signature.digest().encode('base64').rstrip('\n')

        request.headers.update({
            'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature_b64,
            'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
            'CB-ACCESS-KEY': self.api_key,
            'CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE': self.passphrase,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
        return request

api_url = 'https://api.pro.coinbase.com/'
auth = CoinbaseExchangeAuth(API_KEY, API_SECRET, API_PASS)

# Get accounts
r = requests.get(api_url + 'accounts', auth=auth)
```

This is the code directly from the webpage, when i run it with the correct values(API_KEY, API_SECRET, API_PASS) it moans saying that the key needs encoding before hashing.

the key itself looks something like this 36jGMCGkfpyjsnrywCz/sYL6K4nd6Iy41CTe8ovhVWh2EjforFSAkhrH7nyovzqgLWzBcvIIUjyCy3Eku+weSg==

which i believe is base64 encoded, so when i change the variable of hmac_key to = `b'36jGMCGkfpyjsnrywCz/sYL6K4nd6Iy41CTe8ovhVWh2EjforFSAkhrH7nyovzqgLWzBcvIIUjyCy3Eku+weSg=='`

it still tells me that the code needs encoding first through this error message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris\Documents\New folder\import csv.py", line 35, in <module>
    signature = hmac.new(encoded_key, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\hmac.py", line 170, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\hmac.py", line 93, in __init__
    self.update(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\hmac.py", line 113, in update
    self._inner.update(msg)
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

however the API documents says that i need to decode the secret key/hmac_key first which is what their code is doing.
can someone please shed some light on this before i frisby the laptop out the window

Comment: What exactly is giving what error exactly?

Comment: Please post the *complete* error with back trace so we know *what* exactly is complaining about what.

Comment: @deceze i have included the full error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have encoded both the message and the key with the .encode() method and it has worked. I now have a hmac object saved to memory

Answer (score 1):

Most of encryption algorithms (I believe, HMAC included) expects data in binary. So you should `.encode()` key before calling `hmac.new()`.

Wild guess – this docs on website is from py2 times and weren't updated

Comment: Thanks for your answer. unfortunately i get the same error. ive added 'encoded_key = key.encode()'  however running the code again produces the same error

Comment: i have encoded both the message and the key with the method described in your answer and it has worked. I now have a hmac object saved to memory